# Is "verb+か... verb+かしている" a fixed pattern?

Tags: clause-pattern

恐らく、随意領域で士道の鼻と口を塞いでいる**か**、士道の周囲の酸素濃度を下げる**かしている**のだろう。

Hi. I understand the meaning of the sentence. But I have never seen している used after the "か... か" pattern. Is "verb+か... verb+かしている" a fixed pattern? If it is, could you show me how to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give your translation of the sentence please? I'm struggling.

Comment: Perhaps they either stopped Shido's nose and mouth with "territory", or they decreased the concentration of oxygen surrounding Shidou.